`user` not returned from Sign in with Apple REST API
I have tried everything to get the user field returned with Sign in with Apple REST API, and it never does, not for new users, not even if I create a new app!  Working with Apple is so frustrating, and you have to pay for it!!
Referencing the following link, I am using scope=name email. I have tried using + and %20 as the spacer and neither makes a difference. I have also tried setting response_type = code and code id_token (again with + and %20 as the spacer) which also doesn't make a difference.  Always the id_token is returned and always the email, but never the user.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms#3332115
AUTHORIZE REQUEST
https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?
{
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": "com.example.service",
    "scope": "name email",
    "state": "77264297-813c-4738-83ef-f1b77daea04c",
    "redirect_uri": "https://example.com/auth/apple/callback",
    "code_challenge_method": "S256",
    "code_challenge": "2SJCneEpjKcN.....xIIHnpqcvjK_Y0s",
    "access_type": "offline",
    "nonce": "1734523662",
    "response_mode": "form_post"
}

TOKEN REQUEST
https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token?
{
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": "c870aaec987a14.....dqakaGP4Yn1nH3dnPgww",
    "client_id": "com.example.service",
    "client_secret": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI....3izij6dojYfdV6JMdbQPx3sOA",
    "redirect_uri": "https://example.com/auth/apple/callback",
    "code_verifier": "38hHUC....mYuE0zfYVNTycg"
}

RESPONSE
{
    "access_token": "a2b70e12d38b446....4hA7-RLNj0ifU5Q",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": "rb4ed9be2b4024......w5RWjVFUQ",
    "id_token": "eyJraWQiOiJyQlJmV.......0Df0ihEJiA"
}

JWT
{
  "iss": "https://appleid.apple.com",
  "aud": "SERVICE_ID",
  "exp": 1734606699,
  "iat": 1734520299,
  "sub": "000000.f7f7c0ac.....db9fad7e19.1111",
  "nonce": "NONCE",
  "at_hash": "NAfjmciTi2NtmPYIMAgjig",
  "email": "abc123@privaterelay.appleid.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "is_private_email": true,
  "auth_time": 1734520297,
  "nonce_supported": true
}

